# Slice a 3D matrix with a list of first-dimension indices and its corresponding second-dimension indices in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How do I slice a 3D matrix with a list of first-dimension indices and its corresponding second-dimension indices?

For example, given

```
>> A = cat(3, [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9], [10 20 30; 40 50 60; 70 80 90], [100 200 300; 400 500 600; 700 800 900])

A(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


A(:,:,2) =

    10    20    30
    40    50    60
    70    80    90


A(:,:,3) =

   100   200   300
   400   500   600
   700   800   900
```

I want to slice out `A(2, 3, :)` and `A(1, 2, :)` to get `[6 60 600; 2 20 200]`.

I failed with

```
>> A([2, 1], [3, 2], :)

ans(:,:,1) =

     6     5
     3     2


ans(:,:,2) =

    60    50
    30    20


ans(:,:,3) =

   600   500
   300   200
```

I believe there's a one-liner/elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the desired elements subscripts should be converted to indices (`sub2ind`), but before it a 3D transpose (`permute`) should be applied so the third dimension becomes the first.

```
idx = [2 3; 1 2];
[m n z]= size(A);
B=permute(A,[3 1 2]);
result = B(:,sub2ind([m,n],idx(:,1),idx(:,2)))
```

Comment: I was almost there, but I thought I shouldn't mix up the linear indices with `:`. May I ask why the `permute` is necessary?

Comment: I could not find any explanation about such an indexing feature in Mathworks documentation. But  [Octave manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Advanced-Indexing.html) about advanced indexing noted that if we have a matrix with n dimensions and we want to index it with m subscripts, when m < n and one of the indices m(i) is outside the size of the current array, then `the last n-m+1 dimensions` are folded into a single dimension with an extent equal to the product of extents of the original dimensions. So  we should place the first two dimensions in the `last`

Comment: This explanation makes sense! Thanks a lot! Yet another example where a free software beats a commercial software to it.